# Trying to append to existing file in c in my own Unix Shell using >> not working

Tags: c, unix, dup2

I'm trying to create my own unix shell and I've hit a wall while trying to append a command such as ls to an existing file, for example.

```
ls >> myOutput
```

I was able to do a basic redirection using `>` to print to an output file and figured doing >> would be quite similar, but I guess I'm wrong.

This is my code:

```
  int pid;
  int in = 0, out = 0, append = 0, j;
  int fd0, fd1, fda;
  char* args[MAX_ARGS];
  char inFileName[64], outFileName[64];
  //used to get arguments for desired command
  //i.e. ls -a -l -t
  get_args(cmdline, args);
  
  //Commands used to exit the shell.
  if(!strcmp(args[0], "quit") || !strcmp(args[0], "exit")) 
  {
    exit(0);
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
  { /* child process */
    for(j = 0; args[j] != '\0'; ++j)
    {
      if(strcmp(args[j], ">>") == 0)
      {
        args[j] = NULL;
        strcpy(outFileName, args[j + 1]);
        printf("You want to append data to existing file\n");
        append = 2;
      }
      if(strcmp(args[j], "<") == 0)
      {
        args[j] = NULL;
        strcpy(inFileName, args[j + 1]);
        printf("input file name is %s\n", inFileName);
        in = 2;
      }
      if(strcmp(args[j], ">") == 0)
      {
        args[j] = NULL;
        strcpy(outFileName, args[j + 1]);
        printf("output file name is %s\n", outFileName);
        out = 2;
      }
    }
    //printf("in is %d and out is %d\n", in, out);
    if(!strcmp(args[0], "|"))
    {
      printf("You want to pipe info\n");
    }
    if(append)
    {
      **//here is where my issue occurs**
      if((fda = open(outFileName, O_RDWR|O_APPEND)) < 0)
      {
        perror("Error appending data\n");
        exit(0);
      }
      dup2(fda, STDOUT_FILENO);//1
      close(fda);
    }
    if(in)
    {
      if((fd0 = open(inFileName, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0)
      {
        perror("Couldn't read from input file\n");
        exit(0);
      }
      //Changes where the command will read from STDIN to a input file.
      dup2(fd0, 0);
      close(fd0);
    }
    if(out)
    {
      if((fd1 = creat(outFileName , 0644)) < 0)
      {
        perror("Coudln't create output file\n");
        exit(0);
      }
      dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);//1
      close(fd1);
    }
    execvp(*args, args);
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(-1);
  }
  else if(pid > 0)
  { /* parent process */
    
      waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
  } 
  else
  { /* error occurred */
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
  }
```

Please let me know if you would like further details. Any help would truly be appreciated.

Comment: `args[j] = NULL;` then the next `if` uses `args[j] = NULL;` in `strcmp`: undefined behaviour. use `else` or `continue`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This actually solved my issue, thank you so much.